# In bash `$-` yields `himBHs` but `i` and `s` are invalid options -- what's going on?

Tags: bash, posix-compliant

```
$ echo $-
himBHs
$ set -h
$ set -i
bash: set: -i: invalid option
set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]
$ set -m
$ set -B
$ set -H
$ set -s
bash: set: -s: invalid option
set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]
```

As a result I can't use this method to restore bash state using

```
oldstate="$(set +o); set -$-"                # POSIXly store all set options.
.
.
set -vx; eval "$oldstate"         # restore all options stored.
```

as described in this [Unix & Linux answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/310963/247579)

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

EDIT/CONCLUSION:
As [the answer below](https://askubuntu.com/a/1254593/723997) informs, the content of `$-` includes settings having nothing to do with `set`, despite the `set` man entry stating

> The current set of options may be found in $-.

which is true, but confusing by omission.

When recording state, use of `$-` is not required because all the options are already able to recorded for resetting with

```
% restoreState=$(shopt  -po ; shopt -p)
```

or more selectively for a subset of options, e.g.,

```
shopt  -po | grep -E 'brace|glob' ; shopt -p | grep glob
```

Comment: Strangely, my Bash version (4.3.48, on 16.04) accepts `set -i` without complaining, even though it is not documented in `help set`, but `set -s` fails just like in your case.

Comment: @ByteCommander - Good idea to mention version info.

Comment: There's [a comment about this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310957/how-to-restore-the-value-of-shell-options-like-set-x/310963#comment1056405_310963)  on the linked post - my guess is it simply doesn't make sense to try to set an already running shell to be interactive (or to read commands from stdin?) from within

Comment: @steeldriver - Missed that one - thank!  That leaves 's'.

Comment: What is your end goal? I guess you could replace `set -$-` with `set -${-//[is]}` for use interactively

Comment: @steeldriver - Very helpful.  In the end, I'm not sure whether the settings in `$-` aren't already covered by `shopt -po` and `shopt -p`, in which case `$-` isn't really necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the bash man page, right near the top, says

> OPTIONS
>
> > All  of the single-character shell options documented in the description of the `set` builtin command, including `-o`, can be used as options when the shell is invoked.  In addition, `bash` interprets the following options when it is invoked:

And the goes on to describe `-i` and `-s` (in addition to the perhaps more well-known `-c` and `-l`)

"***In addtion***" being the key bit there.

Relevant chapters from the *Bash Reference Manual*:

- [*Invoking Bash*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html): discusses the `bash -i` option (*force the shell to run interactively*) and the `bash -s` option.
- [*Interactive Shell*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Interactive-Shells.html)
- [*Special Parameters: `$-`*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#index-_002d): explains the meaning of `$-`:

  > **Expands to the current option flags as specified** upon invocation, by the set builtin command, or **those set by the shell itself (such as the `-i` option)**.
- [*The Set Builtin*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html): lists further options which may appear in `$-`, such as `-h`, `-m`, `-B`, `-H` (compare to your example `himBHs`).